# Bash: Alias declaration and behavoir in functions

Tags: bash, function, alias

After some trial and error I found out that aliases are not recognized when used within a function, if the alias is declared after the function declaration. Perhaps I'm mistaken but the bash man page does not seem to address this behavior. Take for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
unalias -a
shopt -s expand_aliases

alias alias1=echo

function foo {
echo "Aliases in foo:"
alias
alias1 "Hello from foo!" #Succeeds
}

foo

function bar {
echo "Aliases in bar:"
alias
alias2 "Hello from bar!" #Fails
}

alias alias2=echo
bar
```

Output:

Aliases in foo:

alias alias1='echo'

Hello from foo!

Alias in bar:

alias alias1='echo'

alias alias2='echo'

./aliastest.sh: line 23: alias2: command not found

As seen in this example, the alias command in bar does contain alias2=echo but does not recognize the command when called. In short I don't understand bash' behavoir in this case. Perhaps I don't understand the man page correctly on this matter?

Comment: Why are you using aliases in the first place?

Comment: @chepner Its a question out of curiousity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Bash manual

> Aliases are expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed.

This means you should put your alias before your functions.  It has the advantage that you incur the expansion cost once, and thereafter at each function invocation does not require handling aliases.

When Bash is executing a script, it will execute statements in the order they are read.  A function statement does not execute the function, it defines it (kind of like a variable assignment).  As they are read, functions are saved in memory, and when they are called in a command the shell will not go back to the actual file on disk, but will execute them as stored in memory, without worrying about expanding aliases.

Someone, somewhere, decided that re-doing alias expansion upon every function call was wrong, wasteful, or maybe too unpredictable (changing aliases down the line could cause an already defined function to actually change), and decided against it, preferring to perform alias expansion at the time of function definition.

This also means that if a function is forcefully redefined, for instance by sourcing the script again, any new alias will be expanded.  Functions are not frozen : they can be "re-assigned", although the main idea of a function is usually to be able to call it repeatedly without having to redefine it, so you would usually not use aliases as if they were variables or parameters, changing from one invocation to the next.

You probably find this intuitive when it comes to putting your function declarations at the top of your script, and the actual call at the bottom.  Remember that aliases are to functions as functions are to commands : an alias must be defined before being available for functions being declared, in the same way that a function must be declared before being referenced in an a command.

Comment: Alright, thank you. That part of the manual was kind of confusing for me. Do I understand correctly that bash first reads in the script in its entirety before execution (explaining why the alias command in bar does show the two found aliases)?

Comment: @BennixDeprîx  Please se update answer with additional explanations.  Scripts are executed in the order the statements are read (Bash will not read the whole script before executing the first command it finds), but defining a function (which is done in the same order) is not the same as calling it, but it does something (not just reading the lines), and any required alias must be defined before that something is performed..